# How to get client ip running a Node.js app in Docker behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I've can't retrieve the client IP address inside my docker container

[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeFKX.png)
(I didn't put the Dockerfile in the following examples, but it's a basuc one)

I'm using Koa as a Node.js server and I already enabled proxy.

```js
// server.js

const Koa = require('koa');

const app = new Koa();

// Based on Koa's doc it's required to access X-Forwarded-For
app.proxy = true;

app.use((ctx) => {
  ctx.body = ctx.ip;
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Listening');
});
```

The compose file is basic

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
```

The Nginx conf is based on internet searches.

```
# nginx.conf

events {

}

http {
  server {
    listen    80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:5000;

        proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}
```

When I go on http://localhost I get the container IP `172.22.0.1`.
I would like to be able to get the client IP.

Comment: You seem, already, to be putting the client ip into a custom header (X-Real-IP) via an nginx rule. Your node.js code just needs to read it.

Comment: Here are my headers
```json
{
"host": "localhost",
"x-real-ip": "172.22.0.1",
"x-forwarded-for": "172.22.0.1",
"x-forwarded-proto": "http",
}
```

And I don't have client IP

Comment: I don't think this is unexpected when debugging on a single system as it will choose the bridge interface to route into the container. localhost is not bound to your eth0 interface (or whatever it may be) so theres no reason to pick that.